# Function of two variables Table

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I have a function of two variables `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]` to which I want to find its values for a given range of `zqes` and `zh`.

The first problem is, I want `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]` to give a value for say, `zqes=0.937858` and `zh=1`, `zqes=9.30684` and `zh=10`, and so on. The `Table` that I wrote below evaluates `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]` for `zqes=0.937858` and ALL `zh`, then proceeds to `zqes=9.30684` and ALL `zh` again, and so on. So what I want should produce only 11 values for `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]`, how should I do this?

The second problem is, `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]` will have a range of around `~[-155, -1.47]`, to which `tz[0.1, 0.937858, 1] = -1.47` (Max value for `zh=1`) and `tz[0.1, 93.0506, 100] = -155` (Min value for `zh=100`). In the `FindRoot` line of my code I set the search range to be `{t, -1.2, -200, 0}` but why is finding `tz[0.1, zqes, zh]` produces some error like `The point {-1.2} is at the edge of the search region...`

````
d = 3;
ag = 6;
pg = 6;
wp = 10;
torootL[al_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := al - ((2 zl Sqrt[(1 + t^2 (1 -(zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1])/((d + 1) (zl/zh)^(d + 1))) NIntegrate[x/Sqrt[(1 - x^2) (1 - (((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/zh)^-6) x^3)], {x, 0, (zl/zh)^2}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
tz[al_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := t /. FindRoot[torootL[al, t, zl, zh], {t, -1.2, -200, 0}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]

In[108]:= tzList = Table[tz[0.1, zqes, zh], {zqes, {0.937858, 9.30684, 18.6124, 27.9182, 37.2237, 46.5288, 55.8341, 65.1388, 74.4432, 83.7471, 93.0506}}, {zh, {1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}]

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {86.5934328105432153458601759241399254869861325536822348289974}. NIntegrate obtained 1.56949422762797476134702692399833712204785593227582473073534-121.292776422049311975665999308525652348615116650629201734954 I and 0.598935835823095879488732088256231272482268679212473514418771`60. for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {86.5934328105432153458601759241399254869861325536822348289974}. NIntegrate obtained 1.56949422762797476134702692399833712204785593227582473073534-121.292776422049311975665999308525652348615116650629201734954 I and 0.598935835823095879488732088256231272482268679212473514418771`60. for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {86.5934328105432153458601759241399254869861325536822348289974}. NIntegrate obtained 1.56949427826409832284230728405949350830183983616138886512567-121.292776353861452832569246171990054728109868720739971672617 I and 0.598935827627696875159785645877019653242788626650765046709032`60. for the integral and error estimates.

During evaluation of In[108]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ncvb will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[108]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {-1.2} is at the edge of the search region {-200.0000000000000,0} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[108]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

During evaluation of In[108]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::slwcon will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[108]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {-1.2} is at the edge of the search region {-200.0000000000000,0} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[108]:= FindRoot::reged: The point {-1.2} is at the edge of the search region {-200.0000000000000,0} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

During evaluation of In[108]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::reged will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[108]= {{-1.471551293, -2.215779632, -2.215814401, -2.215816261, \
-2.215816574, -2.215816660, -2.215816691, -2.215816704, -2.215816710, \
-2.215816713, -2.215816715}, {-1.2, -15.50176577, -22.97536070, \
-23.20017521, -23.23716426, -23.24723138, -23.25084319, -23.25239079, \
-23.25314176, -23.25354138, -23.25376974}, {-1.2, -1.2, -31.01646875, \
-44.66098537, -45.96631187, -46.29912053, -46.41638235, -46.46628998, \
-46.49043553, -46.50326522, -46.51059034}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, \
-46.52851902, -65.07238194, -68.00769950, -68.95369435, -69.34412174, \
-69.53052120, -69.62891714, -69.68489720}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, \
-62.04170567, -84.54277049, -89.32829175, -91.11761198, -91.93933961, \
-92.36517587, -92.60507659}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, \
-77.55674550, -103.3216290, -110.0106225, -112.7868873, -114.1644888, \
-114.9236328}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -93.07071265, \
-121.5803427, -130.1463546, -133.9919437, -136.0163442}, {-1.2, -1.2, \
-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -108.5876350, -139.4370608, \
-149.8147737, -154.7709946}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, \
-1.2, -1.2, -124.1060283, -156.9768022, -169.0842074}, {-1.2, -1.2, \
-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -139.6268987, \
-174.2617740}, {-1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, -1.2, \
-1.2, -155.1497506}}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MapThread" is your friend. Here is your corrected code:

```
d = 3;
ag = 6;
pg = 6;
wp = 10;
torootL[al_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 al - ((2 zl Sqrt[(1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1])/((d + 
         1) (zl/zh)^(d + 1))) NIntegrate[
    x/Sqrt[(1 - 
         x^2) (1 - (((1 + t^2 (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1))^-1)^-1) (zl/
               zh)^-6) x^3)], {x, 0, (zl/zh)^2}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, 
    PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
    Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
tz[al_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 t /. FindRoot[torootL[al, t, zl, zh], {t, -1.2, -200, 0}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp]

tzList = MapThread[
  tz[0.1, #1, #2] &, {{0.937858, 9.30684, 18.6124, 27.9182, 37.2237, 
    46.5288, 55.8341, 65.1388, 74.4432, 83.7471, 93.0506}, {1, 10, 20,
     30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}]


(* {-1.471551293, -15.50176577, -31.01646875, -46.52851902, \
-62.04170567, -77.55674550, -93.07071265, -108.5876350, -124.1060283, \
-139.6268987, -155.1497506} *)
```

Comment: The first one works but the last one does not work.

Comment: Sorry the last one was a copy/ paste error, it does not belong to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MapThread[{#1, #2, tz[0.1, #1, #2]} &
, {{0.937858, 9.30684, 18.6124,27.9182, 37.2237, 46.5288, 55.8341, 65.1388, 74.4432, 83.7471,93.0506}
, {1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}}]
(*{{0.937858, 1, -1.471551293}, {9.30684, 10, -15.50176577}, {18.6124,20, -31.01646875}, {27.9182, 30, -46.52851902}, {37.2237,40, -62.04170567}, {46.5288, 50, -77.55674550}, {55.8341,60, -93.07071265}, {65.1388, 70, -108.5876350}, {74.4432,80, -124.1060283}, {83.7471, 90,-139.6268987}, {93.0506,100, -155.1497506}}*)
```